# My JavaScript Fade-in on-scroll function is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a website with a fade-in on scroll JavaScript function but it doesn't seem to be working. I have added my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I want to be able to fade-in the `.hideme` class on-scroll which for some reason has not been working for me. I have never built a fade-in function before so this is pretty new to me.

I am trying to make it work on `<div>` so that I can implement the same throughout the website. Sorry I couldn't upload the pictures!

The desired output would essentially be that the `<div>`s that have the same classname as in the function itself would fade-in on scroll. So the text and the picture in the `<div>` named `.hideme` in html file would fade in on scroll.
Things I have tried -

1. So I tried to change the opacity of the `<div>` in question to create a transition.
2. Changed the classname just in case
3. Called the javascript function in multiple places
4. Ran the function on codepen to see if it works there (and it does!)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){
    
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){
            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);
                    
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #000000;
}

nav {
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-style: italic;
}

.logo {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 70%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li a::before, .nav-links li a::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    width:0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FFFF00;
    transition: .2s width ease-in-out;
}
    
.nav-links li a::before{
    left:0;
}
    
.nav-links li a:hover::after, .nav-links li a:hover::before{
    width: 50%;
} 

.burger {
    display: none;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: #000000;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.nav-active {
        transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.background{
    background: url("../images/Forwebsite_Mrlight.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 950px;
    background-position: center; 
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
}

.background:hover{
    background: url("../images/2Forwebsite_Mrlight.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 950px;
    background-position: center; 
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
}

.hideme{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.hideme aside{
    width: 50%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    font-size: 23px;
    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
}

.hideme img{
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 80px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/mrlight.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Psoppins%26display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/mrlight.png" alt="logo" style="width: 200px"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="philosophy.html" target="_blank">Philosophy</a></li>
            <li><a href="whyUs.html" target="_blank">Why Mr.Light</a></li>
            <li><a href="approach.html" target="_blank">Approach</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script>
        function navSlide() {
            const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
            const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
            const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
            
            burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
                //Toggle Nav
                nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
                
                //Animate Links
                navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
                    if (link.style.animation) {
                        link.style.animation = ""
                    } else {
                        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
                    }
                });
                //Burger Animation
                burger.classList.toggle("toggle");
            });
            
        }

        navSlide();
    </script>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <!-- <img src="images/background.png" class="background"> -->
    <div class="hideme">
        <aside>
            <p>
                Architectual Lighting is the silent partner for our life's spaces.
            </p>
            <p>
                Everywhere.
            </p>
            <p>
                Since 1998 we have combined creativity, innovation and curiosity with advanced technology and reliability. Our strength is rooted in our love for this wonderful profession, for the materials, for the know-how that comes from experience accumulated over many years.
            </p>
        </aside>
        <img src="images/indexpic1.png">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Let me know how I can fix this problem! Would appreciate any feedback/advice or help.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - The title should give a summary of the actual problem. Explain what the [mcve] is supposed to do, what it does instead, if there are any errors (if so post them, copy&paste), and what you've tried so far to solve this on your own.

Comment: Just edited a couple of things in the question. Let me know if you need anything else.